# Messed up origin point

Tags: origin

Sometimes after I do some modifications with model or duplicate and do some modifications then the origin point of the model goes out of the model and it becomes hard to rotate/scale and do anything else with the model.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Some screenshots could help to understand what modifications you do and what happens after. It sounds like you move the model in Edit mode, then in Object mode origin point of the object will be away from the geometry since it won't move. Make sure to grab objects only in Object mode.

Comment: The origin point is  local coordinate (0, 0, 0).   Vertices use local coordinates.  Moving vertices  in edit mode moves their location relative to the origin. Eg if you edit default cube, select all verts and move all 2 units in any direction, it's origin will be outside the mesh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the T pannel (on the left in the 3D view) in object mode with the object selected, there is a set origin button. Try using the set origin to geometry or center of mass functions. If those dont give you the result you want, try placing the 3D cursor where you want the center to be and use set origin to 3D cursor.